# Ubuntu 20.10 dropbox stuck on syncing after crash

Tags: nautilus, dropbox

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10. This has happened twice to me. The first time I had only synced a few files before it happened. I clicked on the Ubuntu notification saying "X files have synced" (X is some number). The Dropbox folder associated with those files opened as expected, but when I tried to close it it reopened. Upon trying again, the same thing happened. Again and again. I couldn't get rid of the nautilus window. Interestingly if in the same nautilus window that was open, I changed to a different folder, it would also open a new nautilus window.

Eventually Dropbox crashed and the nautilus file window no longer kept opening after I closed it. However, Dropbox would no longer download any files upon restarting it (and restarting my computer etc). It always says "syncing" but nothing happens. The green ticks and blue syncing circles on files in the Dropbox folder in nautilus are also gone.

I fixed this the first time by deleting the whole Dropbox folder, all the .dropbox* folders, and uninstalling Dropbox.

This time, I had successfully downloaded my whole Dropbox folder. Everything was working well until I again clicked on an Ubuntu "X files have synced" notification. The exact same thing as described above happened. Dropbox crashed. Now Dropbox says "syncing" and does nothing.

I don't want to delete all my Dropbox folders and re-download them again. Is there anything I can do to get to the bottom of this?

I have tried reinstalling dropbox with `sudo apt remove dropbox` and reinstalling it with `sudo apt install dropbox`. I have tried `dropbox-nautilus` instead. I have tried deleting the .dropbox* files only and reinstalling Dropbox etc. I have tried restarting my computer. I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting my Dropbox account to the computer.